# SQL Update rows if have in the end a specific number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a table called **Account**, and inside it I have a column called **Price_details**.

I want to update the value of this column in case it have in the end "-1" or "-2" to increase one "1" so for example:

- "*Test-Value-1*" -> it should increased by +1 -> "*Test-Value-2*"

**I should update all rows ending with "-" + number so I increase 1.**

I tried many solutions but it's not worked in my case.

Anyone have idea how I can do that?

Comment: Show us your best UPDATE attempt.

Comment: Why do you have the value of interest as part of a string with other data - that's your problem.

Comment: I tried this but it's looks i need days to make it done one by one: REPLACE(string, old_string, new_string)

Comment: @Stu I'm not professional and I still learning, I have a case and trying to solve it. beside i tried to search how to check string in sql if it has a number and replace it, but i did not found anything so far

Comment: You need to show your existing code / attempt and add clarity to your requirements.

Comment: Do you need to update only values that have in the end "-1" or "-2" or any number? Can it be more than 1 digit, like "-345"?

Comment: If this is coming from a class, be aware that it appears that they are teaching bad database design to have columns that hold such compound values. I would question the quality of the education you are getting in that class and perhaps do some self-study on "database normalization". If they start teaching examples involving columns holding comma-separated lists or dates stored as a character type, run and run far.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic yes exactly bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of *string_split* and *string_agg*, here is a trivial example

```
select STRING_AGG(value, '+') FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ')
```

So for adding a +1 at the end assuming there are no other numbers you could use something like this

```
select isnull(convert(varchar, try_convert(int, value) + 1), value)
FROM STRING_SPLIT('test-value-1', '-')
```

now lets join it together again

```
select string_agg(isnull(convert(varchar, try_convert(int, value) + 1), value), '-')
FROM STRING_SPLIT('test-value-1', '-')
```

To update you can then use this example simulating your table with a variable

```
declare @t table (col varchar(20))

insert into @t (col) values 
('test-value-1'),
('test-value-2'),
('test-value-3'),
('test-value-4')

select * from @t

update @t set col = (select string_agg(isnull(convert(varchar, try_convert(int, value) + 1), value), '-')
FROM STRING_SPLIT(col, '-'))

select * from @t
```